# ruby - cinch irc bot - everything after a word

Tags: ruby, irc

Bad title, but I dont know how to describe it.

```
on :message, "\.addfact" do |m|
  open('facts.txt', 'a') { |f|
    f.print "\n *XXXXXX* ~ #{m.user.nick}"
  }
  m.reply "Fact added, #{m.user.nick}"
end
```

Basically, whenever someone in the IRC channel the bot is on does this:

> <random_irc_user>.addfact This is a fact. But it includes dots ... , and smileys =) :)

the little bot here is gonna append it to a text file, with the formatting

> This is another fact but its on an other line and was added earlier =) ~ Cool_guy
>
> This is a fact, it includes dots ... , and smileys =) :) ~ random_irc_user

I've got the new line, and "random_irc_user" part working,
but i have no idea how to do the actual fact. I guess arguments or similar but I'm not really sure about them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a regular expression and capture everything after your command:

```
on :message, /^\.addfact (.+)/ do |m, fact|
  File.open('facts.txt', 'a') { |f| f.puts "#{fact} ~ #{m.user.nick}" }
  m.reply "Fact added!"
end
```

Comment: sorry i dont really understand... this is what i tried to do

    on :message, /^\.addfact (.+)/ do |m, fact|
    open('facts.txt', 'a') { |f|
    f.print "\n ~ #{m.user.nick}"
    }
    m.reply "Fact added!"
    end

Comment: You used my exact example? the `fact` variable will contain the string you want to add to your file. So you can go ahead and add that code. What part do you not understand?

Comment: # .. add fact string . and im not sure how im gonna get the actual fact into the txt

Comment: That's a comment.. that's the part where you write the code yourself. You have the `fact` string, so you can open your facts file and append that string as you did before.

Comment: Anyway, I just updated the example to provide the code you have already written yourself

Comment: ok it seems to work (i get Fact added!) but it wont write it to the txt

Comment: You have used my exact code after I updated it? This opens `facts.txt` and appends the text.

Comment: okay now it wrote to the txt. but kinda messed up  ~ ChatterHello lol ~ Chatter

Comment: OK it works perfectly, i removed the old facts.txt so i started fresh. Thank you so much!!